# Apache Beam , how to GroupBy in a List of Objects

Tags: java, apache-beam

I have a list of cars objects in a PCollection.
`PCollection<List<Car>>`

Each car has a color.

I want to sort this list where the color is the key and cars that have that color are the values and end up with a `KV<String, List<Car>>`

{"red":[car1,car2],"green":[car3,car4]}

```
Car car1 = new Car();
Car car2 = new Car();
Car car3 = new Car();
Car car4 = new Car();
    
car1.setColor("red");
car2.setColor("red");
car3.setColor("green");
car4.setColor("green");

final List<Cars> cars = Arrays.asList(car1,car2,car3,car4);
PCollection<Car> carsCollection = pipeline.apply(Create.of(cars));


PCollection<KV<String, List<Car>>> sortedCars = carsCollection.apply(...)
```

Maybe something like this wold work

```
PCollection<KV<String, List<Car>>> sortedCars =
   cars.apply(WithKeys.of(new SimpleFunction<String, List<Car>>() {
       @Override
        public String apply(Car car) {
            return cat.getColor();
        }
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the Core [GroupByKey](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#groupbykey) transform.

For your WithKeys you can also make use of the lambda

```
(WithKey.of(x -> x.getColor())).apply(GroupByKey.create())
```

This will produce a KV<key,Iterable>